# Kendo UI Grid select by data item

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid with a large datasource and paging.

I have an event that fires where I know the underlying data item that I want to select, but am unsure on how to programatically page/select this item in the grid. If the item is not on the current grid page, I cannot use datasource.view() to poke through when the data is not on the current page.

Does anyone know how I can select an item by its underlying data source object?

I've got a similar situation to where i am at @:
http://jsfiddle.net/Sbb5Z/1050/
I can get the data item with the following:

```
 change: function (e) {
      var selectedRows = this.select();
      var dataItem = this.dataItem(selectedRows[0]);
   }
```

But then I don't know how to select the same row in the other grid.

Basically in the select event of one grid, I want to go select the same item in another grid. These are not the same datasource, as they have different page setups, but it is the same underlying data array.

I have the data item in the target grid -- but I have no clue how to page/select it in the target grid.

*Edit:*
The best I've come up with sofar is creating a datasource with the same parameters as the original, and paging through it programatically, until I find what I am looking for. Surely there must be a better way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've gotten this back from Telerik, and is a little cleaner:

http://jsfiddle.net/RZwQ2/

```
function findDataItem(theGrid, dataItem) {
//get grid datasource
var ds = theGrid.dataSource;

var view = kendo.data.Query.process(ds.data(), {
                filter: ds.filter(),
                sort: ds.sort()
            })
            .data;

var index = -1;
// find the index of the matching dataItem
for (var x = 0; x < view.length; x++) {
    if (view[x].Id == dataItem.Id) {
        index = x;
        break;
    }
}

if (index === -1) {
    return;
}

var page = Math.floor(index / theGrid.dataSource.pageSize());    
var targetIndex = index - (page * theGrid.dataSource.pageSize()) + 1;    
//page is 1-based index    
theGrid.dataSource.page(++page);
//grid wants a html element. tr:eq(x) by itself searches in the first grid!    
var row = $("#grid2").find("tr:eq(" + targetIndex + ")");
theGrid.select(row);

console.log('Found it at Page: ' + page + 'index: ' + targetIndex);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a common id, or field in the data that you can use to uniquely identify the object in the other dataSource, because the kendo generated UID's are not going to be the same accross two different DataSource instances.

Most generally you define the id in the Model you bound to the grid, which you can use to quickly pluck items from the datasource

```
change: function (e) {
  var selectedRows = this.select();
  var dataItem = this.dataItem(selectedRows[0]);

  var otherItem = otherGrid.dataSource.get(dataItem.id) // will get
}
```

if you don't have a common ID field specified in the model, but do know how to find the item you can loop through the data source looking for it

```
var selectedRows = this.select();
var dataItem = this.dataItem(selectedRows[0]);
var data = otherGrid.dataSource.view();

var otherItem;

for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
    if( data[i].myCommonField === dataItem.myCommonField ) {
       otherItem = data[i];
       break;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

to select the item in the other grid you need to do this:

```
 var elements = otherGrid.items(),
     element;

 element = elements.filter("[data-uid='" + otherItem.uid + "']")

 otherGrid.select(element) // to select just the one item

 //OR
 otherGrid.select( otherGrid.select().add(element) ) // to add the item to the current selection
```

I the fiddle you provided uses a really old version of kendo Grid where this won't work...I just realized. are you stuck on the 2011 version? I can probably get something to work at least in theory but the above will work in the newer versions

essentailly you need to match the item you have to a DOM element, in later versions you can use UID because the dom elements all get that on them "data-uid" it looks like if you at `id` to your `model: { }` def you can get the tr elements to have `data-id` which you can use to select the right select using jquery. I use the `items()1 method which also doesn't seem to exist on the early version but you can use`grid2.table.find("tr[data-id=]")` instead I believe

Comment: I do have a common id (the fiddle isnt the best example). I can find the data item in the target data source -- but how do I get the grid to page/select that data item? My main problem is when the item is not on the grid's current page. I will update the fiddle..

Comment: I've updated the fiddle. I have the "otherItem" -- but have no idea how to page to /select that item in the 2nd grid.

Comment: Therein lies the rub. Grid2.items() only has stuff on the current page.

Comment: well yeah, you can only select something that exists, do you want to page through until the element exists? in that case first navigate to the correct page: grid2.dataSource.indexOf(otherItem) / pagesize to get the page, use the page() method to go to the page, then do items() select

Comment: Still messes up if there is a sort. I reaaally don't want to have to scroll through all the pages and look. Seems rather silly you can't do this sort of thing

Comment: hmnm, i would suggest using the .view() method to get the data rather then .data() (or ._data), which would preserve your sort, but I imagine that also respects the page, and only returns the current page? You could load the raw data into a new daaSource, and apply the current filter, sort, but not page, and then get the index. I don't know if that is better then looping but it may be. something like new newds.query($.extend(true {},dataSource.filter(), dataSource.sort()))

Comment: Yeah, that is what i am ending up doing. I can get the filter/sort, but not page, then determine the page once I get the raw index. With a little caching (only regenerate datasource if filter/sort/data change) it is not too bad.

Comment: great, at least its a solution. Friendly reminder to pass on some upvotes, or accept the answer, if this was helpful to you. thanks!

Comment: It was indeed helpful. I am trying to get a better solution from Telerik / etc before I close this out

Answer (score 2):

Assume div id will be **Grid** then first we need find the kendoGrid

```
var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
```

then call the **grid.select()** to select the currently selected one
finally call the **grid.dataItem()** to get the selected item.

```
var selectedDataItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
```

Comment: Right. OP was to select the same item in another list, by the object reference. This isn't explicitly available and you have to iterate until you find it, sadly.

Comment: I am getting grid.select is not a function (type error)

Comment: check you are given proper div id or not

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon others, I have a method that takes a single (or multiple) ids to match against:

```
function selectItems(grid, idAr)
{
  if(!idAr instanceof Array)idAr = [idAr];
  var items = grid
    .items()
    .filter(function(i, el)
    { 
      return idAr.indexOf(grid.dataItem(el).Id) !== -1; 
    });
  grid.select(items);
}
```

* Obviously Id could be replaced by any field that is in your data item.

Use for selection:

```
selectItems(grid, "5");
selectItems(grid, ["6", "7"]);
```