# Focus on a cell in second page in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a requirement to bring focus on the error cell on kendo-Grid using a "**next error**" Button.

But i am facing a issue in bringing the focus on the cell. If the error cell lies in the second page of the kendo grid.

My Code:

```
function nextErr(){

var grid = angular.element('#myGrid').data('kendoGrid');
var dataItems = grid.dataSource.data();
var index;
var uid;
for(var i=0; i < dataItems.length; i++){
    if(!isNullOrUndefined(dataItems[i].errors)
        && !angular.element.isEmptyObject(dataItems[i].errors)){
        index = i;
        uid = dataItems[i].uid;
        break;
    }
}
var errorCell = angular.element("tr[data-uid='"+ uid +"'] td[data-err-msg != 'undefined']")[0];
grid.editCell(errorCell);
```

}

If anyone has implemented something similar please let me know

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the angular library however the Kendo grid will give you it's state. This is where you'll find the page...var state={        columns: grid.columns,
        page: dataSource.page(),
        pageSize: dataSource.pageSize(),
        sort: dataSource.sort(),
        filter: dataSource.filter(),
        group: dataSource.group()} I use a bit of jquery to grab it but you can do the same thing with angular. hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a similar problem I used ideas from [Kendo UI Grid select by data item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775423/kendo-ui-grid-select-by-data-item). Here is my own slightly modified function to find a dataItem in a grid.

```
function findDataItem(dataSource, dataItem) {
    if (!dataItem) {
        return null;
    }

    var view = kendo.data.Query.process(dataSource.data(), {
        filter: dataSource.filter(),
        sort: dataSource.sort()
    }).data;

    var index = -1;
    // find the index of the matching dataItem
    var ID = 'YOUR_ID_FIELD_NAME';
    for (var x = 0; x < view.length; x++) {
        if (view[x][ID] == dataItem[ID]) {
            index = x;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (index === -1) {
        return null;
    }
    var page = Math.floor(index / dataSource.pageSize());
    var targetIndex = index - (page * dataSource.pageSize());

    return {
        page: ++page,
        index: targetIndex,
    }
}
```

Then you can use the returned `page` to show a corresponding page in the grid `dataSource.page(page)`.

Hope that helps.